# C# take output and put it into CSV file

Tags: c#

I have some code that is currently doing the following at the end of the code:

```
Console.WriteLine(vid.totalCurrentCharges + " : " + vid.assetId + " : " + vid.componentName + " : " + vid.recurringCharge);
Console.readline().
```

I need to take the output of `vid.totalCurrentCharges + " : " + vid.assetId + " : " + vid.componentName + " : " + vid.recurringCharge`, and write It to a csv file. Can someone here help with this? Currently all it is doing is writing the output to console.

Comment: Another solution, `File.AppendAllText("output.csv",string.Join(",", vid.totalCurrentCharges, vid.assetId, vid.componentName, vid.recurringCharge) + "\n");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Console.Writeline you need to create StreamWriter. Just like this:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.csv"))
{
//probably a loop here
   writer.WriteLine(vid.totalCurrentCharges + " , " + vid.assetId + " , " + vid.componentName + " , " + vid.recurringCharge);
}
```

Moreover you can use `String.Join` to concatenate strings instead of "adding" them, so above `WriteLine` can be converted into:

```
writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", vid.totalCurrentCharges, vid.assetId, vid.componentName, vid.recurringCharge));
```

Comment: So you've gone from `:` to `;`, neither of which is a comma.

Comment: where would the path be for important.csv since it is not specified?

Comment: @Amicheals in current working directory of `exe` file

Comment: @crashmstr you are right fixed (stupid polish version of CSV)